# Training a NN classifier on a single\double channel out of a surround sound dataset

Tags: audio-processing, neural-network, conversion

I want to train a neural network for a classification task on the [VSD2014 dataset](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283095619_VSD2014_A_dataset_for_violent_scenes_detection_in_Hollywood_movies_and_web_videos). I have downloaded the movies, but they have a 6 channel audio format (surround sound). 6 channels will cost a very long training time, and so, I wish to trail on a single\double channel first, in order to prove the concept.

Is it better to convert into a stereo or single channel? If so, how do I convert this on MATLAB? Can I get away with, simply, choosing one of the channels? If so, which one? I am guessing the subwoofer channel is not the best choice. I do not even know which one is the subwoofer channel.

How do I train a NN classifier on a single\double channel out of a surround sound dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the order of a 5.1 channel signal is as follows: L (Left), R (Right), C (Center), LFE (Low frequency enhancement), Ls (Left surround), Rs (Right surround).

What you need is a downmix and there are many downmixing methods. Here's the recommendation of ITU:

$$
L' = L+0.7071C+0.7071Ls
$$$$
R' = R+0.7071C+0.7071Rs
$$

However, multichannel signal may contain some hidden information for your classification task. To get a better performance, I don't think downmixing to single channel is a good idea. Stereo signals may be a compromise between performance and training time.

Comment: You are very correct in your comment about the classification information. However, I can experiment with a low number of channels to get the sense of what is better and then proceed to test using all 6 channels.